# Хранение zip данных на сервере

Tags: android, сервер, хранение-данных

Есть приложение на Android. Во время работы в приложении, пользователь может загрузить дополнительный контент (темы). Раньше это было зашито в приложение, но с ростом количества тем, приложение стало весить слишком много, и потребовалась возможность загрузки только тех тем, которые пользователь хочет. Контент должен где-то храниться в виде zip файлов. Каждый файл занимает около 10 - 20 мб, таких файлов 8 штук, но в дальнейшем количество может увеличиваться. Каждый файл, пользователь может загрузить отдельно. Установок в день около 1000-1500. В худшем случае, каждый пользователь может скачать все 8 файлов, т.е. 240 гб в день.

Где и как лучше всего хранить эти данные?

P.S. Есть хостинг на machost. Выдержит ли он такую нагрузку?

В серверной части полный ноль, если можно отвечайте попроще.

Comment: выдержит, тут же просто файлик отдать